# Swing & Batik: Create an ImageIcon from an SVG file?

Tags: java, swing, svg, icons, batik

Simply put, I'm looking for a way to make an ImageIcon from an SVG file using the batik library.  I don't want to have to raster the SVG to disk first, I just want to be able to pull an svg out of the jar file and have it land as a UI element.

I feel like this should be reasonably easy, but the batik javadocs aren't telling me what I need to know.

(Why batik?  Well, we're already using it, so we don't have to run another library past legal.)

Answer (score 26):

It's really quite easy, just not very intuitive.

You need to extend `ImageTranscoder`. In the `createImage` method you allocate a `BufferedImage`, cache it as a member variable, and return it. The `writeImage` method is empty. And you'll need to add a getter to retrieve the `BufferedImage`.

It will look something like this:

```
    class MyTranscoder extends ImageTranscoder {
        private BufferedImage image = null;
        public BufferedImage createImage(int w, int h) {
            image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            return image;
        }
        public void writeImage(BufferedImage img, TranscoderOutput out) {
        }
        public BufferedImage getImage() {
            return image;
        }
    }
```

Now, to create an image you create an instance of your transcoder and pass it the desired width and height by setting `TranscodingHints`. Finally you transcode from a TranscoderInput to a null target. Then call the getter on your transcoder to obtain the image.

The call looks something like this:

```
    MyTranscoder transcoder = new MyTranscoder();
    TranscodingHints hints = new TranscodingHints();
    hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, width);
    hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, height);
    transcoder.setTranscodingHints(hints);
    transcoder.transcode(new TranscoderInput(url), null);
    BufferedImage image = transcoder.getImage();
```

Simple, right? (Yeah, right. Only took me 2 weeks to figure that out. Sigh.)

Comment: Yep, what Devon said. :)  Here's my SVGIcon class which pretty much does that: http://mcc.id.au/2005/04/SVGIcon.java

Comment: Would be nice to know what package those classes are supposed to be in.

Comment: @mmm it's been a while, but it should be something like `org.apache.batik.transcoder` or a sub-package of that.

Comment: My program reports like "org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: Unspecified transcoding hints: KEY_DOM_IMPLEMENTATION" from hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, (float)1); I don't know the reasons.

Comment: @M_L_Sing_Jump_Rap It is a 13 year old answer, so there have undoubtedly been some changes. See the answers by John Doppelmann and Dov Wasserman that includes several extra hints. But not that's still 7 years ago, so there may be more changes required.

Answer (score 4):

I have just followed Devon's approach with Batik-1.7

However, in order to make it work I had to make the following additions to the hints object:

```
MyTranscoder transcoder =new MyTranscoder()

DOMImplementation impl = SVGDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation();
TranscodingHints hints = new TranscodingHints();
hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, width); // e.g. width=new Float(300)
hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT,height);// e.g. height=new Float(75)
hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOM_IMPLEMENTATION, impl.getDOMImplementation());
hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT_NAMESPACE_URI,SVGConstants.SVG_NAMESPACE_URI);
hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT_NAMESPACE_URI,SVGConstants.SVG_NAMESPACE_URI);
hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT, SVGConstants.SVG_SVG_TAG);
hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_XML_PARSER_VALIDATING, false);

transcoder.setTranscodingHints(hints);
TranscoderInput ti=new TranscoderInput(uri)
transcoder.transcode(ti, null);
BufferedImage image = transcoder.getImage();
```

Seems like something has been updated in batik's XMLAbstractTranscoder( http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xmlgraphics/batik/tags/batik-1_7/sources/org/apache/batik/transcoder/XMLAbstractTranscoder.java) with version 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using Devon's and John's suggestions, which nearly worked for me. I had to make some tweaks as follows, feel free to use:

```
package com.corp.util;

import static org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH;
import static org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT;
import static org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT_NAMESPACE_URI;
import static org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.KEY_DOM_IMPLEMENTATION;
import static org.apache.batik.util.SVGConstants.SVG_NAMESPACE_URI;
import static org.apache.batik.util.SVGConstants.SVG_SVG_TAG;

import com.google.common.flogger.GoogleLogger;

import org.apache.batik.anim.dom.SVGDOMImplementation;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscodingHints;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.annotation.concurrent.ThreadSafe;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

/** Loads SVG images from disk. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics. */
@Singleton
@ThreadSafe
public class SvgImageLoader {

  private static final GoogleLogger logger = GoogleLogger.forEnclosingClass();

  /**
   * Reads in an SVG image file and return it as a BufferedImage with the given width and a height
   * where the original aspect ratio is preserved.
   *
   * @param url URL referencing the SVG image file, which is typically an XML file
   * @param width width in pixels the returned BufferedImage should be
   *
   * @return a valid image representing the SVG file
   * @throws IOException if the file cannot be parsed as valid SVG
   */
  public static BufferedImage loadSvg(URL url, float width) throws IOException {
    SvgTranscoder transcoder = new SvgTranscoder();
    transcoder.setTranscodingHints(getHints(width));
    try {
      TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(url.openStream());
      transcoder.transcode(input, null);
    } catch (TranscoderException e) {
      throw new IOException("Error parsing SVG file " + url, e);
    }
    BufferedImage image = transcoder.getImage();
    logger.atInfo().log("Read '%s' SVG image from disk requested with width=%.1f, sized as %dx%d pixels.",
        new File(url.getFile()).getName(), width, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    return image;
  }

  private static TranscodingHints getHints(float width) {
    TranscodingHints hints = new TranscodingHints();
    hints.put(KEY_DOM_IMPLEMENTATION, SVGDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation());
    hints.put(KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT_NAMESPACE_URI, SVG_NAMESPACE_URI);
    hints.put(KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT, SVG_SVG_TAG);
    hints.put(KEY_WIDTH, width);
    return hints;
  }

  private static class SvgTranscoder extends ImageTranscoder {

    private BufferedImage image = null;

    @Override
    public BufferedImage createImage(int width, int height) {
      image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      return image;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeImage(BufferedImage img, TranscoderOutput out) {}

    BufferedImage getImage() {
      return image;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid passing dom parameters :
    `transcoder.setTranscodingHints((Map<?, ?>) hints);`

Comment: That should be a comment for @John Doppelmann right? Then don't "answer" it please, use comments if possible.