# Load SVG file in javafx 2.0

Tags: java, svg, javafx-2

I'd like to display a svg image in javafx 2.0, but I don't find such a thing in the API. I guess it's because it's still in beta.

Until the final release, how can I load a svg ? Is there already a library which can handle that, or do I need to parse myself the file and then create the corresponding shapes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2495501/852274) question I found a working solution.

**1. Include references to the [Batik SVG Toolkit](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/download.cgi) jars**

**2. Implement your own Transcoder**
(based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495501/swing-batik-create-an-imageicon-from-an-svg-file/2495712#2495712) answer by [Devon_C_Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98811/devon-c-miller))

```
class MyTranscoder extends ImageTranscoder {

    private BufferedImage image = null;

    @Override
    public BufferedImage createImage(int w, int h) {
        image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeImage(BufferedImage img, TranscoderOutput out) {
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }
```

}

**3. Get a BufferedImage from your svg**
(based on hint in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495501/swing-batik-create-an-imageicon-from-an-svg-file/6634963#6634963) answer by [John Doppelmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836584/john-doppelmann))

```
String uri = "path_to_svg/some.svg";

MyTranscoder transcoder = new MyTranscoder();
TranscodingHints hints = new TranscodingHints();
hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, 20f); //your image width
hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, 20f); //your image height
hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOM_IMPLEMENTATION,    SVGDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation());
hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT_NAMESPACE_URI, SVGConstants.SVG_NAMESPACE_URI);
hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT, SVGConstants.SVG_SVG_TAG);
hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_XML_PARSER_VALIDATING, false);

transcoder.setTranscodingHints(hints);
TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(url.toExternalForm());
transcoder.transcode(input, null);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = transcoder.getImage();
```

**4. Create an InputStream from BufferedImage**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

JPEGImageEncoder imageEncoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(outputStream);
imageEncoder.encode(bufferedImage);

byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

**5. Add the image to your ImageView**

```
//javafx.scene.image.Image
Image image = new Image(inputStream);
//javafx.scene.image.ImageView
ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
imageView.setImage(image);
this.getChildren().add(imageView);
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks ! But don't javafx handle raw image data ?

Comment: @Mr_Qqn: Currently I don't know about any support concerning handling raw image data. Personally, I would prefer an ability of the API to convert SVG files to Java code as described [here](http://silveiraneto.net/2008/11/21/inkscape-and-javafx-working-together/).

Comment: But unlike fx scripts java classes are compiled, so I don't think that would be a good thing.

Comment: 4. After you get buffered image, you could do byte[] bytes = bufferedImage.toByteArray(); ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes); BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputStream);  Image im = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null);

Answer (score 3):

I used @pmoule's answer above, but had better luck replacing his steps 3-5 with this:

```
MyTranscoder imageTranscoder = new MyTranscoder();

imageTranscoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, (float) width);
imageTranscoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, (float) height);

TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(new FileReader(file));
imageTranscoder.transcode(input, null);

BufferedImage bimage =  imageTranscoder.getImage();
WritableImage wimage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bimage, null);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(wimage);
<panel-vbox-whatever>.getChildren().clear();
<panel-vbox-whatever>.getChildren().add(imageView);
```

Simpler, and it just worked better for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2264379&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

you do not need batik, you can try WebView like this:

```
WebView view = new WebView();
view.setMinSize(500, 400);
view.setPrefSize(500, 400);
final WebEngine eng = view.getEngine();
eng.load("http://127.0.0.1/demo1.svg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the SVG to FXML and then it becomes trivial.  The conversion can be done with XSLT.  You can get the stylesheet from here:

http://jayskills.com/blog/2012/06/03/svg-to-fxml-using-netbeans/

Then after conversion to FXML you can load it as a Node with the built-in FXMLLoader:

```java
FXMLLoader.setDefaultClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
URL location = KayakMain.class.getResource("path/to/my/resource.fxml");
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(location);
```