# JavaFX: how to use matrix transformations of SVG

Tags: svg, javafx-2

it's me again :)

My question today focusses SVG. Within SVG, you can group different `<path>` elements within a `<g>` tag for being able to call transformations for all paths at once. Additionally, there are some transformations / operations which only can be called on groups, not on paths directly.

I have an SVG source I need to display in my UI, containing different elements like described above. So I have something like:

```
<g id="myId" transform="matrix(-1,2.4336e-008,-2.4336e-008,-1,2163.78,1161.93)">
  <path .../>
</g>
```

Currently I'm using SVGPath and a Stackpane, which works quite well. I'm just wondering how I could deal with the matrix transformation? As there is no according SVGGroup class, I guess I have to implement this myself, rules are described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined).

Am I on the right way or do I miss something again? Would you maybe recommend [using Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854601/load-svg-file-in-javafx-2-0) instead of dealing with the SVG stuff (though I don't know exactly how this would help in this special case concerning the matrix transformations).

As everytime, any recommendation is appreciated :)

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FX transforms:

```
    SVGPath path = new SVGPath();
    path.setContent("M50,50 L100,50 L100,100 L50,50 Z");
    path.getTransforms().add(
         Transform.affine(-1,2.4336e-008,-2.4336e-008,-1,2163.78,1161.93));
```

Your numbers are a bit extreme, but for simple transforms I've tried `matrix` parameters are the same as `Transform#affine` ones.

Comment: Sergey: you're my hero of the day :) Works great and did the trick, thank you sooo much :)