# Create a non-buffered java.awt.Image from an SVG file

Tags: java, svg, batik

I have some existing code which looks a lot like the solution on [Swing & Batik: Create an ImageIcon from an SVG file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495501/swing-batik-create-an-imageicon-from-an-svg-file)

But the destination for my image is PDF, and it bugs me that when you zoom into the PDF, you see pixels. If the source and destination data are both vector graphics, it should be possible to render directly.

The library we're using (iText) takes a java.awt.Image, but I can't seem to figure out how to get a java.awt.Image which renders an SVG. Does Batik have some way to do that?

Comment: Converting an SVG image to a `java.awt.Image` converts the SVG to a pixel representation of the SVG, it does not preserver the vector information.  I don't know if it will help, but you might like to take a look at [this](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=263) which was the first hit I got of Google for "iText SVG"

Comment: Hmm... Converting to a java.awt.BufferedImage at least throws away the vector information, but I was under the impression that because java.awt.Image is abstract, drawing one shouldn't have to be resolution dependent.

Comment: `Image` is still backed by pixel data (in most cases), especially when it's rendered to a graphics context

Comment: Yeah, since it was "in most cases", I assumed that one of the remaining cases would allow me to back it with an SVG. :) As for that example, PdfGraphics2D's constructor is private. I guess it's for a different version of iText, but I thought we were up to date.

Comment: To get `Image` to work in iText, iText would need to provide the implementation, as iText would only know how to paint it within it's given context.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's what I ended up doing. `java.awt.Image` was certainly a dead-end. There was a solution in the form of wrapping up a `PdfTemplate` in an `ImgTemplate` so that it could be used as an iText `Image`.

(I had to have it in something which knew its size, because it's being used in a table and the layout would go completely crazy otherwise. An `Image` seems to know this.)

```
public class SvgHelper {
    private final SAXSVGDocumentFactory factory;
    private final GVTBuilder builder;
    private final BridgeContext bridgeContext;

    public SvgHelper() {
        factory = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(
            XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName());
        UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgentAdapter();
        DocumentLoader loader = new DocumentLoader(userAgent);
        bridgeContext = new BridgeContext(userAgent, loader);
        bridgeContext.setDynamicState(BridgeContext.STATIC);
        builder = new GVTBuilder();
    }

    public Image createSvgImage(PdfContentByte contentByte, URL resource,
                                float maxPointWidth, float maxPointHeight) {
        Image image = drawUnscaledSvg(contentByte, resource);
        image.scaleToFit(maxPointWidth, maxPointHeight);
        return image;
    }

    public Image drawUnscaledSvg(PdfContentByte contentByte, URL resource) {
        GraphicsNode imageGraphics;
        try {
            SVGDocument imageDocument = factory.createSVGDocument(resource.toString());
            imageGraphics = builder.build(bridgeContext, imageDocument);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load SVG resource", e);
        }

        float width = (float) imageGraphics.getBounds().getWidth();
        float height = (float) imageGraphics.getBounds().getHeight();

        PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(width, height);
        Graphics2D graphics = template.createGraphics(width, height);
        try {
            // SVGs can have their corner at coordinates other than (0,0).
            Rectangle2D bounds = imageGraphics.getBounds();

            //TODO: Is this in the right coordinate space even?
            graphics.translate(-bounds.getX(), -bounds.getY());

            imageGraphics.paint(graphics);

            return new ImgTemplate(template);
        } catch (BadElementException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't generate PDF from SVG", e);
        } finally {
            graphics.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to set the dock icon using an SVG image, so I needed an ImageIcon.  After a week of trying, I came up with this solution to obtain an ImageIcon from any of the formats supported by Java.  It converts the SVG to a PNG if necessary.  The strRes is a resource string.

```
protected static ImageIcon loadIcon(String strRes) {
    if (strRes == null || strRes.isEmpty()) {
      return null;
    }
    // For new ImageIcon(resource, strRes), strRes must NOT begin with "/":
    //   get Exception from PluginClassLoader says "leading '/' doesn't work; strip"
    if (strRes.startsWith("/")) {
      strRes = strRes.substring(1);
    }
    ImageIcon icon = null;
    if (!strRes.contains(" | ")) {
      URL resource = StudioIcons.class.getClassLoader().getResource(strRes);
      if (resource != null) {
        if (strRes.endsWith(".svg")) {
          // To load an ImageIcon from an SVG is "af kapores" (you need to throw a chicken over your head 3 times)
          // This solution converts the image to a PNG and writes it out, then reads it in.
          try {
            Image image = SVGLoader.load(resource, 1f);
            String filename = new File(resource.getPath()).getName() + ".png";
            ImageIO.write((BufferedImage)image, "png", new File(filename));
            icon = new ImageIcon(new File(filename).toURI().getPath(), "Converted from SVG");
          }
          catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot convert SVG to PNG: ", ex);
          }
        } else {
          try {
            icon = new ImageIcon(resource, strRes);
          } catch (Exception ignore) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return icon;
}
```

**To set the dock icon, I use:**

```
  if (Taskbar.isTaskbarSupported() ) {
    final Taskbar taskbar = Taskbar.getTaskbar();
    try {
      //set icon for MacOS (and other systems which support this method)
      taskbar.setIconImage(icon); // Was Java Duke
    } catch (final UnsupportedOperationException e) {
      System.out.println("The OS does not support: 'taskbar.setIconImage()'");
    } catch (final SecurityException e) {
      System.out.println("There was a security exception for: 'taskbar.setIconImage()'");
    }
  }
```